# Fatal Error :1:1: Premature end of file. Error reading url

Tags: java, xml, string, inputstream, bufferedreader

Hello i am trying to read a URL feed with an interval and store it as an object. However when i try to run it, it gives me this error [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.

Here is the code:
thisUrl is a static http address

```
url = new URL(thisUrl);
URLstream = url.openStream();
ir = new InputStreamReader(URLstream);
buff = new BufferedReader(ir);
String xObject = "";

while (buff.ready()) {
     String temp = buff.readLine();
     xObject += temp;
}
```

After using the stream i will close it

```
URLstream.close();
ir.close();
buff.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the docs for the return type and value of the ready() method

> True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.

Your next read() may well block on the stream. That does not mean you are done reading the stream. Use this instead.

```
String temp = null;
while ( (temp = buff.readLine()) != null) {
     xObject += temp;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code that you have given to me. I would like to thank you for your solution. 

I did try several ways by closing the stream and even seperated the declaration. 

Why is the way i code will cause a block on the stream?(I am suspecting networking problems, but i don't know if i am right on this one)

Comment: No problem. If you want detailed clarifications on how ready() and readLine() work, please feel free to raise another question. The folks on SO will help you out.